# code is failing after adding airship for push

Tags: iphone, xcode

My code is failing with the following error:
"Clang failed with exit code 1"

This is the error screenshot

[image: Error screenshot]

I thought this was because of the AirShip I added, but after i deleted all of its components and commented out all the methods it is still giving me this error.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Did you delete the files through Xcode or Finder/Terminal?

Comment: I looked into the folders and only saw empty folders. Deleted those as well.

Comment: This is complaining about SBJSON being missing, not urban airship.

Comment: I think somewhere you have imported "nsstring + sbjson.m" and you either deleted that file or removed the reference from your project.

Comment: The file is there. Positively.